# Connecting faces that are out of alignment

Tags: faces

I'm working on a face mask in Blender. I have gotten to the point where I'm trying to make ear loops for it. I've used the spin tool and gotten it pretty close, but I can't think of how to line up these faces or rotate the whole ear portion without it looking wonky. I feel like this is an easy answer, but I've lost some skill on Blender the past few months. Pictures are included. Please let me know how to solve this!

[image]

[image: Far View]

[image: Close View - 1]

[image: Close View - 2]

Comment: Does your loop need to be exactly semicircular, or just smooth?

Comment: @RobinBetts Just smooth. I'd love it to be pretty close, but I don't think it matters too much as long as people know that it's an ear loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not a bad candidate for modelling with a curve and a profile, but you might be surprised by what <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>E</kbd> > *Bridge Edge Loops* can do.

[image]

In the foreground there are a couple of yellow faces, slightly pitched along the desired arc, to set everything off in the right direction. Behind, in blue, the same two faces, linked with *Bridge Edge Loops*, with *Blend Path* set, quite a few *Cuts*, and other settings at default. You might have to flip one end's normals, in your case, to get it to work, or use the perimeters of regions of deleted faces, with the same vertex count.

In your case, you're right about wrangling the orientation of the bridge. The algorithm by which Bridge Edge Loops decides which way to go is apparently not as simple as detecting normals..

[image]

So you can give it some hints. Here, I deleted an equal region of faces at both ends, selected both the perimeters, and <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>S</kbd> put *Cursor to Selected*, between the holes. I <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>D</kbd> duplicated one of the perimeters, and with the Cursor as pivot, in an appropriate view, rotated the duplicate to about the halfway angle. Then bridged the 3 profiles (in one operation), adjusting *Smoothness*.

You could dupe from both ends, tweak the in-betweens, maybe *Loop-Tools* turn the profiles into circles for a tubular band...

Comment: This is all working brilliantly. However, I did encounter the normals situation you described above. And whether I choose the face, or the perimeter of a deleted face, it still wants to go the opposite way on one end. I've tried flipping the normals and it won't switch. I've even looked at the overlay for normal direction and tried both ways and it won't switch. I'm happy to edit my question to add pics of what I'm talking about, if you'd like.

Comment: @Chase  maybe share on https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/?

Comment: Thanks! I'd forgotten about that. I updated my original post with the link.

Comment: @Chase You're right... _So frustrating!_.. :D ... see edit to answer.

Comment: I appreciate your time and patience on helping me solve this one! Thanks, Robin!

Answer (score 2):

If I'm understanding your question:

1. Select the ear loop and detach it from the rest of the mesh pressing <kbd>L</kbd>;
2. Activate the proportional editing with <kbd>O</kbd>;
3. Select the end-face of the loop (the one you want to bring to the mask mesh);
4. Move it with <kbd>G</kbd> and setting the action radius with the mouse wheel (be careful not to reach the other end with a big radius, or you'll move it too).

Comment: Setting the Prop. Edit to 'Connected Only' will prevent interference with the rest of the mask..

Comment: Right! I forgot it! :-)